# PHP Link does not work

Tags: php

```
echo "<td><input name='Send' type='button' value='Submit' onClick=location.href='save.php?myDocRegNo=$A&docCat=$C&dcrNo=$Dcr_No
    &metTown=$Town_Code&dcrDate=$Dcr_Date&repCode=$Rep_Code&db=$Dbase' /></td>";
```

I have above link echoed in my php file and all my `$` variables are set with values and the link works perfect.

But when I add two more variables `&fullTown=$Town&fullRep=$FlRp` to the same link and try to submit nothing happens and link does not work.Can anybody can identify the error ?Is there a variable limit for a HTML link?

```
echo "<td><input name='SendTest' type='button' value='SubmitTest' onClick=location.href='save.php?myDocRegNo=$A&docCat=$C&dcrNo=$Dcr_No
    &metTown=$Town_Code&dcrDate=$Dcr_Date&repCode=$Rep_Code&db=$Dbase&fullTown=$Town&fullRep=$FlRp' /></td>";
```

Comment: could be something with the values of `$Town` and `$FlRp`. Try making them a single known character and try.

Comment: Your second statement is working from my end. echo "<td><input name='SendTest' type='button' value='SubmitTest' onClick=location.href='save.php?myDocRegNo=$A&docCat=$C&dcrNo=$Dcr_No&metTown=$Town_Code&dcrDate=$Dcr_Date&repCode=$Rep_Code&db=$Dbase&fullTown=$Town&fullRep=$FlRp' /></td>";

Comment: Make sure you are not getting special character in your variables.

Comment: can you please show the values of all the variables what you used in the two links?

Answer (score 0):

please try this code its working fine

```html
please try this code its workin fine 

echo '<button onclick="window.location.href=\'save.php?myDocRegNo='.$A.'&docCat='.$C.'&dcrNo='.$Dcr_No.'&metTown='.$Town_Code.'&dcrDate='.$Dcr_Date.'&repCode='.$Rep_Code.'&db='.$Dbase.'&fullTown='.$Town.'&fullRep='.$FlRp.'\'">Continue</button>';
```

echo 'Continue';

Answer (score 0):

please use this code it is working, i think there was only some blank space issue and i have change `location.href` change to `window.location.href` and it is working properly.
here is the code

```
echo "<td><input name='Send' type='button' value='Submit' onClick=window.location.href='save.php?myDocRegNo=$A&docCat=$C&dcrNo=$Dcr_No&metTown=$Town_Code&dcrDate=$Dcr_Date&repCode=$Rep_Code&db=$Dbase' /></td>";
```